# Add Form Data on PHP mail script

Tags: php, html, forms, email, phpmailer

i am using PHP form with File attachment. Due to low knowledge in PHP i use this script from a online tutorial.

My problem is:

1. I want to get all user submitted form info by mail but don't know how to add code on this script(check last code section).
2. I want user can only send only .txt, .doc, .docx file format on file attachment.

HTML Code:

```
<form name="sendmail" action="form.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<ul>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label for="name">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="f_name" />
        </span>
        <span class="left" style="position:relative;left:30px;">
        <label for="name">Middle Name:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="m_name" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label for="name">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="l_name" />
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label for="email">Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" size="40" id="email" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label for="email" style="width:200px;">Confirm Email Address:</label>
        <input type="email" size="40" id="c_email" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
    </li>       
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label for="name">Primary Phone: </label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="p_phone" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label for="name" style="width:200px;">Secondary Phone:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="s_phone" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label for="name">Mailing Address:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="m_address" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label for="name" style="width:200px;">Mailing City:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="m_city" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label for="name">State/Province:</label>
        <input type="text" size="30" id="state_province" />
        </span>
        <span class="left" style="position:relative;left:30px;">
        <label for="name">Zip/Postal Code:</label>
        <input type="text" size="30" id="zip_postal" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label for="name">Country:</label>
        <input type="text" size="30" id="country" />
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label for="name">Job Information:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="job_info" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label for="name" style="width:200px;">Desired Job Title: </label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="job_title" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label for="name" style="width:200px;">Desired Geographic Region:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="job_info" style="width:200px;" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label for="name" style="width:200px;">Years of Related Experience:</label>
        <input type="text" size="40" id="job_title" style="width:250px;" />
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="left">
        <label>Resume:</label>
        <input type="file" name="resume" />
        </span>
        <span class="right">
        <label style="width:180px;">Cover Letter:</label>
        <input type="file" name="cover_letter" />
        </span>
    </li>
</ul>
<p>
    <button type="submit" class="action" name="submit">Submit</button>
</p>
```

form.php code-

```
<?php
$from = "info@arif-khan.net";
$to = "arifkpi@gmail.com";
$subject ="JobSeeker Registration Request";
$message = $_POST['body'];

// Temporary paths of selected files
$file1 = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
$file2 = $_FILES['cover_letter']['tmp_name'];

// File names of selected files
$filename1 = $_FILES['resume']['name'];
$filename2 = $_FILES['cover_letter']['name'];

// array of filenames to be as attachments
$files = array($file1, $file2);
$filenames = array($filename1, $filename2);

// include the from email in the headers
$headers = "From: $from";

// boundary
$time = md5(time());
$boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$time}x";

// headers used for send attachment with email
$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . " boundary=\"{$boundary}\"";

// multipart boundary
$message = "--{$boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$boundary}\n";

// attach the attachments to the message
for($x=0; $x<count($files); $x++){
$file = fopen($files[$x],"r");
$content = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
fclose($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" . " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$filenames[$x]\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $content . "\n\n";
$message .= "--{$boundary}\n";
  }

 // sending mail
 $sendmail = mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

 // verify if mail is sent or not
 if ($sendmail) {
header("location:index.html");
 }
 ?>
```

Field code that i want to add on email body-

```
First Name: $_POST[f_name]
Middle Name: $_POST[m_name]
Last Name: $_POST[l_name]

Email Address: $_POST[email]

Primary Phone: $_POST[p_phone]
Secondary Phone: $_POST[s_phone]

Mailing Address: $_POST[m_address]
Mailing City: $_POST[m_city]

State/Province: $_POST[state_province]
Zip/Postal Code: $_POST[zip_postal]
Country: $_POST[country]

Job Information: $_POST[job_info]
Desired Job Title: $_POST[job_title]

Desired Geographic Region: $_POST[desired_region]   
Years of Related Experience: $_POST[year_of_experience]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add the captured data to the sendmail script:

1. name your variable correctly (that is no space in between), for example,

   ```
    First Name: $_POST[f_name]
    Middle Name: $_POST[m_name]
    Last Name: $_POST[l_name]
   ```

Should be (remember the '$' sign to tell php it is a variable:

```
     $First_Name: $_POST['f_name'];
     $Middle_Name: $_POST['m_name'];
     $Last_Name: $_POST['l_name'];
```

Do the same for all, and place this code before this script:
// Temporary paths of selected files

```
     $file1 = $_FILES['resume']['tmp_name'];
     $file2 = $_FILES['cover_letter']['tmp_name'];
```

1. In your code where you have:

   // multipart boundary
   $message = "--{$boundary}\n" . "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" .

   $message .= "--{$boundary}\n";

Add this:

```
$message .= "First name: ".clean_string($First_Name)."\r\n";

$message .= "Last name: ".clean_string($Last_Name)."\r\n";
```

Do this for all the variable you want to add from (1) above, and your script should now work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Your inputs are missing the `name` attribute. For PHP to capture form values you need to add the `name` attribute to the inputs and then capture the input values by referring to these names. For example:

You are capturing the `First Name` from the from like so:

`First Name: $_POST[f_name]`

So get the name your input should have a name attribute equal to `f_name` like so:

`<input type="text"`**`name="f_name"`**`size="40" id="job_title" style="width:250px;" />`

Comment: Thanks, sorry my mistake. I forget to add name. But after adding name field on every form field still i don't get user submitted info by mail. Can you please tell me how to add code of last section on email body.